# Minicom send automate script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, serial-port

I'm using minicom to test my connection on serial port.

```
 sudo minicom -b 115200 -D /dev/ttyS0
```

in this way minicom opens its 'console-gui' and allow me to send data.

I send:

```
 atz
```

and obtain 'OK'

```
at
```

and obtain 'OK'

Ans so on.

I need to run a script that write to inifinity "at" and read answer..

Any advice?

I evaluate other programs too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Minicom have -S option for executing SCRIPT at startup time,so made a script with your commands like

```
vi script.txt
send atz
send at
```

Run your script with minicom like

```
minicom -S script.txt
```

Also refer http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/runscript1.html for minicom scripting

Comment: In minicom terminal itself

Comment: and what about -b 115200 -D options ?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
minicom -S script.txt -C output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If only "send" AT commands minicom just read the last AT command. You need the follow syntax inside script.txt if you want many AT outputs inside output.txt :

```
send AT
expect "OK"

send ATI
expect "OK"

send AT+CPIN?
expect "OK"
```